# "Bing Error - Out of call volume quota" on first use

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use Blockspring in Excel (and Google Sheets) to access Bing Web Search to return URLs based upon a list of company names (method is described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35U-FKAlaPY). I am receiving this: "#ERROR! Bing Error - Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 15.01:52:46", even though my Microsoft Cognitive Services account shows zero of 1,000 calls used before 1/7/17.  Note that this is a free trial subscription (if that matters). Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: It ended up working in Google Sheets, but not Excel, after I signed up in Azure for a paid account and entered the new key.

Comment: Does your API key work on the API Test Console: https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43eeccf5ff8098cef3807/operations/56b4447dcf5ff8098cef380d/console?

Comment: This will solve it: https://open.blockspring.com/apps.